# Prove $\frac{MN}{FN}=\frac{CP}{CF}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$\triangle ABC$ (AB>BC) with heights AD, BC, DE intersect at H. Circumsribed circle (O) of $\triangle ABC$, draw diameter CK of (O), CK intersect ED at P. Circumsribed circle of $\triangle PFD$ intersect AD at M. Point N in AC (AN=NC)

Prove $\frac{MN}{FN}=\frac{CP}{CF}$

[image]

I try to prove $\triangle MNF \sim \triangle PCF$ but it seems so difficult. I notice that MN//BC but dont know how to prove it and dont know if it helpful for the problem.

Can anyone help me to deal with this problem? Thank you so much

Comment: the statements say nothing about point N.

Comment: @sirous, sorry for my mistake, point N in AC (AN=NC)

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oh, yeah, my mistake in typing. Thank u so much for point it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

As can be seen in figure:

Extend NM to meet the little circle at G and intersect FC at point I. This point is almost the intersection of GN and FP.

$\angle FIN=\angle GIC$

$\angle PGM=\angle PFM$

$\Rightarrow \triangle FIN \sim \triangle GIC $

Therefore:

$\frac {MN}{FN}=\frac {CP}{CF}$

Update: Special case where triangle ABC is isosceles; $AC=BC$. In this case F and P are coincident on F and CF respectively. Also M is on FN. $MP||AC$, so  $triangle FCN\sim \triangle FPM$, therefore:

$\frac{MN}{FN}=\frac {PC}{CF}$

See figure below:[image]

Comment: Excuse me, could u tell me what is point G and I (cause the figure is difficult to see cleary)? Thank u

Comment: @Jnote, I edit my answer.

Comment: Hi @sirous, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4435979/585488